# Necklace Mockup Tool in JavaScript does not always work as expected

Tags: javascript, shopify, mockups

I am using Shopify and a script located at https://app.cjdropshipping.com/static/shopify/pod/pod.js to generate mockups for a necklace product. You basically need to upload a photo and then it takes it and sends it to the server to generate a front and back side cover.

Well, this script does not always work on mobile.

You can try the mockup tool at https://purfectgifts.com/products/petnecklace as well as analyze it.

It does not always capture the whole area of the uploaded image dimensions and does not put the generated image instead of the original product image.

I need to have this fixed for mobile (iPhone & Android). It works better on Desktop.

I think this issue about the script has to do with how it loads itself...

Please help me out with this. You can make me the happiest person in the world if you can help me with that.

I am not a programmer but I tried to change how the script loads.

I think the issue is about how the script is loaded.

I appended the following code right above the closing body tag:

`<script type='text/javascript' async=false defer=false src='https://app.cjdropshipping.com/static/shopify/pod/pod.js'></script>`

Comment: `false` is not a valid value for the `async` or `defer` attributes.